# Convert string/numeric date in Excel to a date formatted object using only formulas

Tags: excel, excel-2007, office-interop, excel-formula

Folks,

I have a string date which I can convert to numeric using:
=DateValue("1/2/2011")
results in 39084

I'm trying to use ONLY FORMULAS to convert either the string or the numeric date into a date formatted object.  Using the UI for formatting is not an option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use TEXT()

example:

```
=Text(DateValue("1/2/2011"), "yyyy/mm/dd")
```

Comment: only issue with that is that I'm using Excel interop with .net and that cell would appear as a String object instead of a DateTime object in .net.

Comment: I could...but that requires a fix to my .net code, whereas no fix is required if I can find the right formula...the above seems to work

Comment: that's another way of saying I'm lazy =)

Comment: Not sure about .NET but check if the cell object has a .Text property - this should give you the value as displayed in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
A1 = Text("1/2/2011", "mm/dd/yyyy")
=DATE(VALUE(MID(A1,7,4)), VALUE(MID(A1,1,2)), VALUE(A1(B10, 4, 2)))
```